# Как достать часть после пробела?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, scanner

Есть строка ввод с консоли. Хотела разделить регулярным выражением по пробелу. Нужно достать часть после пробела, но считывается первая часть

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Account simpleAccount = new Account(1000);
        System.out.println("Баланс обычного счета: " + simpleAccount.getBalance());
        simpleAccount.deposit(2000);
        System.out.println("Баланс обычного счета: " + simpleAccount.getBalance());
        simpleAccount.withdraw(500);
        System.out.println("Баланс обычного счета: " + simpleAccount.getBalance());

        Account cardAccount = new Card(3000, 1);
        System.out.println("Баланс карточного счета: " + cardAccount.getBalance());
        cardAccount.deposit(2000);
        System.out.println("Баланс карточного счета: " + cardAccount.getBalance());
        cardAccount.withdraw(500);
        System.out.println("Баланс карточного счета: " + cardAccount.getBalance());

        Account depositAccount = new Deposit(6000);
        System.out.println("Баланс депозитного счета: " + depositAccount.getBalance());
        depositAccount.deposit(1000);
        System.out.println("Баланс депозитного счета: " + depositAccount.getBalance());
        depositAccount.withdraw(300);
        System.out.println("Баланс депозитного счета: " + depositAccount.getBalance());

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Выберете действие: Проверить баланс = баланс, Пополнить баланс = пополнить, Снять деньги = снять, Выход = выход");


        for (;;){
            String input = sc.next();
            String[] partOfInput = input.split("\\s+");


            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("выход"))
                break;
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("баланс")){
                System.out.println("Баланс обычного счета: " + simpleAccount.getBalance());
                System.out.println("Баланс карточного счета: " + cardAccount.getBalance());
                System.out.println("Баланс депозитного счета: " + depositAccount.getBalance());
            }
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                System.out.println("Введите сумму: ");
                System.out.println(partOfInput);
                System.out.println("Успешно!" + simpleAccount.getBalance() + partOfInput);

            }
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("снять")){
                System.out.println("Введите сумму: " + simpleAccount.withdraw(30));
                System.out.println("Заберите деньги!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Где в коде разделение по пробелу и обращение к части после пробела?

Comment: String[] partOfInput = input.split("\\s+"); вот строка разделения по пробелу, пробовала через индексы обратиться ко второй части, но игнор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас как-то слишком сложно и даже непонятно, что именно делается. Напишите просто

```
String[] partOfInput = input.split(" ");
```

Comment: Выберете действие: Проверить баланс = баланс, Пополнить баланс = пополнить, Снять деньги = снять, Выход = выход
пополнить 8765
Введите сумму: [пополнить]
Успешно!2500.0[Ljava.lang.String;@27973e9b
Просто разбить по пробелу не помогает, он берет первую часть строки

Comment: У вас partOfInput - массив строк. А вы с ним обращаетесь как с обычной переменной. Вам нужно обращаться по индексу, например partOfInput[1].